# mysql: how to split list field

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table which only contains id and a field whose data is a list of data. e.g.

```
--------------
| id |  data  |
| 1  | a,b,c,d|
| 2  | a,b,k,m|
---------------
```

I guess it's not a good design that put a list data in a field, so I want to know how can I redesign it?

Comment: your table have only these two fields??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per me you need two tables i.e. Master and Transaction tables only when some details are gonna be same for every records and some are gonna be changing. In your case if there are not any other thing related to your id field is gonna be same you can carry on with one table and with following structure.

```
--------------
| id |  data  |
| 1  |   a    |
| 1  |   b    |
| 1  |   c    |
| 1  |   d    |
| 2  |   a    |
| 2  |   b    |
| 2  |   k    |
| 2  |   m    |
---------------
```

BUT if there are any other things related to the id fields that is gonna be same for same id records you will have to use two tables.
like following case. there are 3 fields id, name and data.
and you current table looks something like

```
--------------------------
| id |  name    |  data  |
| 1  | testname | a,b,c,d|
| 2  | remy     | a,b,c,d|
--------------------------
```

your new table structure should look like.

table 1 Master

```
-----------------
| id |  name    |
| 1  | testname |
| 2  | remy     |
-----------------
```

Table 2 Transaction

```
    --------------
    | id |  data  |
    | 1  |   a    |
    | 1  |   b    |
    | 1  |   c    |
    | 1  |   d    |
    | 2  |   a    |
    | 2  |   b    |
    | 2  |   k    |
    | 2  |   m    |
    ---------------
```

For better database management we might need to normalize the data.
**Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency**. Normalization usually involves dividing large tables into smaller (and less redundant) tables and defining relationships between them. The objective is to isolate data so that additions, deletions, and modifications of a field can be made in just one table and then propagated through the rest of the database via the defined relationships. You can find more on below links

1. [3 Normal Forms Database Tutorial](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)
2. [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only those two fields in your table then you should have only 1 table as below

```
id | data
```

with composite primary key as `PRIMARY KEY(id,data)` so that there won't be any duplicate data for the respective ID.

The data would be like this

```
id | data
 1 | a
 1 | b
 1 | c
 1 | d
 2 | a
 2 | b
 2 | k
 2 | m
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two tables with a foreign key.

Table 1
id

Table 2
id
datavalue

So the data looks like:

**Table 1:**

```
id
1
2
3
```

**Table 2:**

```
id | data
 1 | a
 1 | b
 1 | c
 1 | d
 2 | a
 2 | b
 2 | k
 2 | m
```

Comment: @FahimParkar It _can_ be a good design depending on requirements, just as your design _can_ be, also depending on requirements. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10976482/533120) for the list of things that should be taken into account when making a decision which of these two to use. +1 to counter undeserved -1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another table which can be of the `ONE to MANY` type.

For e.g. you could have another table datamapping which would have `data` and `ID` column where the `ID` column is a `FOREIGN KEY` to the `ID` column of the data table.

So according to your example there would be 4 entries for `ID = 1` in the datamapping table.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this this is not a good database design. The `data` field violates the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF, which can lead to problems in maintaining and querying the data.

To normalize your design, split the original table in two. There are 2 basic strategies to do it: [using non-identifying and using identifying relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884652/533120).

---

NOTE: If you only have `id` in the parent table, and no other FKs on it, and parent cannot exist without at least one child (i.e. `data` could not have been empty in the original design), you can dispense with the parent table altogether.