# How would you implement a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

One car **must** have **one** owner, and an owner can have many cars.

Comment: one table for cars one for owners, put the owners id as a column in the cars table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
**Owner**
ID

**Car** 
ID
OwnerID
```

Comment: To make the **MUST** in question work, make sure OwnerID is not nullable.

Answer (score 3):

Use a foreign key in the Car relation.

**Car**

carID - Primary Key

ownerID - Foreign key

**Owner**

ownerID - Primary key

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, use two tables and a foreign key between them.

I'd just like to add that there are two general strategies for doing that:

- Using identifying relationship (and migrating parent PK **inside** child PK).
- Using non-identifying relationship (and migrating parent PK **outside** child PK).

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884652/533120) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656173/database-modeling-for-a-weak-entity/10658665#10658665).